# Call to undefined function Symfony\Component\Console\Input\escapeshellarg()

Tags: laravel, symfony

When running `composer install` in production I get a new error message today:

```
$ composer install
Installing dependencies from lock file (including require-dev)
Verifying lock file contents can be installed on current platform.
Nothing to install, update or remove
Package swiftmailer/swiftmailer is abandoned, you should avoid using it. Use symfony/mailer instead.
Generating optimized autoload files
> Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump
> @php artisan package:discover --ansi

   Error

  Call to undefined function Symfony\Component\Console\Input\escapeshellarg()

  at vendor/symfony/console/Input/Input.php:195
    191▕      * @return string
    192▕      */
    193▕     public function escapeToken(string $token)
    194▕     {
  ➜ 195▕         return preg_match('{^[\w-]+$}', $token) ? $token : escapeshellarg($token);
    196▕     }
    197▕
    198▕     /**
    199▕      * {@inheritdoc}

      +1 vendor frames
  2   [internal]:0
      Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput::Symfony\Component\Console\Input\{closure}("package:discover")

      +8 vendor frames
  11  artisan:37
      Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel::handle(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
Script @php artisan package:discover --ansi handling the post-autoload-dump event returned with error code 1
```

I can't figure out what is wrong. I'm wondering if the dependencies have got into a funny state and I need to do a fresh install of the vendor directory?

Comment: Out of curiosity: could you check whether running `escapeshellarg`  in one of your own scripts works properly?

Comment: Tested it, but doesn't work in production... (it does work in development though).

`$ php artisan tinker
>>> escapeshellarg('')
PHP Error:  Call to undefined function escapeshellarg() in Psy Shell code on line 1
>>>`

Comment: It should just be a standard PHP function...
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellarg.php
But it's gone walkies...

Comment: I suspect that the function has been disabled in WHM... PHP-FPM settings... Just trying to get this sorted with the host.

Comment: If you cannot run that function in your own script, talk to the support of your webhoster about this problem

Answer (score 3):

Turns out the function `escapeshellarg()` was disabled by the hosting provider. Thank you Nico for your help!